# Can't start MySQL keeps saying "Server quit without updating PID file"

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat

Can't start MYSQL server it keeps saying "server quit without updating PID file". I tried re-creating the PID file, I added the path to PID file in my.cmf file, but nothing seems to help. I tried renaming the PID file and then starting up and it seemed to start up but then it died right away.

Here's the mysql log:

```
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 92864584624 and 92864584624 in ibdata files do not match the l$
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-07-24 15:27:27 1992 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-24 15:27:28 1992 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-24 15:27:28 1992 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-24 15:27:28 1992 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 92864702613
2015-07-24 15:27:28 1992 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-24 15:27:28 1992 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-07-24 15:27:28 1992 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-07-24 15:27:28 1992 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-07-24 15:27:28 1992 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-07-24 15:27:28 1992 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
150724 15:27:28 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150724 15:27:28 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-07-24 15:27:28 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timesta$
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-07-24 15:27:28 2035 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150724 15:27:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Here's what's in my my.cmf file.

```
[mysqld]
max_connections=500
slow_query_log=1

default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Any ideas what might be a problem?

Comment: `Database was not shutdown normally!` it's crashing. you need to figure out why.

Comment: Is this `Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.` even valid?

Comment: what is a my.cmf file? where is the actual error in your log??

Comment: I meant the `my.cnf` file... As far as why it was not shutdown correctly, how can I find that out?  I am able to start the mysql service using `sudo service mysql start` but it uses up a lot of memory and then just dies again.

Comment: It would say why it is crashing in the error log that you posted above, I just dont see any ERRORs in it...How much memory do you on your box?  how much are your cache and buffer pool set to?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

1) Ensure MySQL has write permission on PID file

1) Go to MySQL data directory remove ibdata files (dont forget to take backup)